# Redirection with parameters and multiple query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I want to redirect this url
`https://www.mydomain.fr/mon-compte-membre/?ihcnewlevel=true&lid=7&urlr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.fr%2Fservices%2F`

To `https://www.mydomain.fr/slug/

**EDIT**
This is the edited code (still not working)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mon-compte-membre/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ihcnewlevel=true(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lid=7(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)urlr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww\.mydomain\.fr%2Fservices%2F [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /slug/ [R=302,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You must use `?` in the target to strip off any previous query string
2. Apache won't decode `%` characters in query string so you will have to match them literally

You may use:

```sh
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /mon-compte-membre/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ihcnewlevel=true(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lid=7(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)urlr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww\.mydomain\.fr%2Fservices%2F [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /slug/? [R=302,L]
```

Once you're satisfied with the result, replace `302` with `301`.

Comment: Thank you . I don't need to strip off the previous strings...It is still not working though

Comment: I edited my post with your code

Comment: Can you try my updated rule now

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not work...

Comment: I have already tested it and it worked pretty well on my local Apache. First verify this .htaccess is being used by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled. If you get 500 then comment out 4th `RewriteCond` line above and retest.